# how to solve this definite integrals?

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sqrt{(r-a)(b-r)}}{r}dr$$ where a and b are constant lower and upper limit. The answer of this integral is $$\pi/2({a}^{1/2}-{b}^ {1/2})^{2}$$ so please give me the hints that how to solve this integral thanks in advanced sir.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: If you let $f(x) = \sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}$, then $f(x) = f(a+b-x)$. How do you use this property to get to the finish line ?

Comment: Thank you. Your hint would be useful, except I have tried now for a day and I've yet to see how to use it properly. Can I have maybe a partial answer? This isn't my homework.